# Swig(Tcl): Can I call Swig function while executing my c++ program?

Tags: c++, tcl, swig

I have a c++ program which have a Tcl interpreter.
I wrap my functions and add them into Tcl interpreter manually. 
Is it possible to wrap and add them by Swig automatically?

Here is the simplified code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tcl.h>

class SystemData {              // I have a class which link to all the data and function
public:
    void print(){
        printf("Hello!\n");
    };
};
                                // I wrap the functions manually. But I'm tired to maintain them.
int Hello( ClientData clientData, Tcl_Interp *interp, int argc, const char **argv ) {
   SystemData* system = (SystemData*) clientData;
   system->print();
}

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();;
    SystemData* system = new SystemData; 
    Tcl_CreateCommand( interp, "hello", Hello, (ClientData)system, (Tcl_CmdDeleteProc *)NULL );

    Tcl_Eval(interp, "hello");  // I have a Tcl interpreter so that I can call any function in any time

    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
}
```

I have tried to export SystemData to Tcl by Swig:

```
// swig.cc
#include <stdio.h>
#include <tcl.h>

class SystemData {
public:
    void print(){
        printf("Hello!\n");
    };
};

SystemData* systemData;
int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Tcl_Interp *interp = Tcl_CreateInterp();;
    systemData = new SystemData; 


    Tcl_Eval(interp, "load ./swig.so swig");
    Tcl_Eval(interp, "puts $systemData");

    Tcl_DeleteInterp(interp);
}
```

My Swig interface:

```
/* swig.i */
 %module swig
 %{
 /* Put header files here or function declarations like below */
class SystemData;
extern SystemData* systemData;
 %}

extern SystemData* systemData;
```

The compile commands:

```
swig -tcl swig.i
g++ -fpic -c swig.cc swig_wrap.c -I/usr/local/include
g++ -shared swig.o swig_wrap.o -o swig.so
```

However, the result of `puts $systemData` is

```
NULL
```

I also tried do not load swig.so
However, the result of `puts $systemData` is

```
can't read "systemData": no such variable
```

Anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the compile commands. My finally commands are:

```
swig -c++ -tcl swig.i
g++ -fpic -c swig.cc swig_wrap.cxx 
g++ -shared swig.o swig_wrap.o -o swig.so
g++ swig.o swig_wrap.o -o swig.out -g -I/usr/local/include -L/usr/local/lib -ltcl8.5
setenv LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/local/lib:/usr/local/lib
./swig.out
```

And the output of above commands are:

```
swig.i:22: Warning(454): Setting a pointer/reference variable may leak memory.
_906e600000000000_p_SystemData
```

Comment: Any recommendation for this type of scenarios ?, without any leakage of data?

Comment: @VenkataVamshi :
I have not yet down the project. But I think it is the same when you code c++.
For example, use getSystemData() and setSystemData() instead of directly accessing systemData.
Thus, you can protect memory in setSystemData().
`    void setSystemData(SystemData* data) {
        /* free old data */;
        systemData = data;
    }`